# Problems running podman in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: containers, podman

Different problems, mainly related to the amount of user namespaces.

Trying to run a pre-built image yields:

```
podman run --rm -it -p8080:8080 --env LOGSTASH_CONF_STRING=$LOGSTASH_CONF_STRING --name logstash bitnami/logstash:latest 
Completed short name "bitnami/logstash" with unqualified-search registries (origin: /etc/containers/registries.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/bitnami/logstash:latest...
Getting image source signatures
# layers
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
  Error processing tar file(exit status 1): potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:4 for /var/log/apt/term.log): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid: lchown /var/log/apt/term.log: invalid argument
Trying to pull quay.io/bitnami/logstash:latest...
Getting image source signatures
# layers...
Storing signatures
  Error processing tar file(exit status 1): potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:4 for /var/log/apt/term.log): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid: lchown /var/log/apt/term.log: invalid argument
Error: 2 errors occurred while pulling:
 * Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:8a5e287f7d41a454c717077151d24db164054831d7cd1399ee81ab2dfba4bcb2": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:4 for /var/log/apt/term.log): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid: lchown /var/log/apt/term.log: invalid argument
 * Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:8a5e287f7d41a454c717077151d24db164054831d7cd1399ee81ab2dfba4bcb2": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:4 for /var/log/apt/term.log): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid: lchown /var/log/apt/term.log: invalid argument
```

So I can't really run this thing. Then trying to run a locally built container which creates a user I get:

```
Error: OCI runtime error: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: setup user: invalid argument
```

Configuration has been set up with subuid

```
jmerelo:100000:65536
```

Although

```
podman unshare cat /proc/self/uid_map
0       1000          1
```

So there must be something that I'm missing or that I should restart here. Even if I log in again, it's still the same result. So there must be something that I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem solved by following [this](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/4075#issuecomment-533817997):

```
rm -rf ~/.config/containers ~/.local/share/containers
podman system migrate
```